# Creating a custom property to use in Spring, JPA e LOG4J xml

Tags: java, spring, jpa, log4j

I have a Tomcat Container with almost 6 applications running in same time, each application have exactly the same structure, code, logic, is exactly the same application but from differents owners.

The only diference between this applications is the folder where logs, database, pictures and another things, are located. I.E: In log4.properties i should configure the log file directory to app1, app2, app3 ... and the same thing to applicationContext.xml (configuring the database locate).

So, i wanna know if i can create a parameter like: "application_name = app1", and use this parameter in everything. Then when i create another app10, i just change this parameter value.

Comment: Can't you use request.getContextPath()?

Comment: But how can i use this method inside a XML or a *.properties ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, i have solved this using Ant Scripts ( Build Scripts). 
Keep one Main ApplicationContext.xml ( where all bean declartions ) and keep indiviual xml file (app1-datasource.xml,app2-datasource.xml) . in the main ApplicationContext.xml i did imported the  file as 
`<import resource="app-dataSource.xml"/>` 
Using build scripts , based on application name it would rename the file app1-datasource.xml to app-datasource.xml in staging space, so that while building war/ear/jar file the app-datasource.xml file will be picked. 
May not be perfect solution , but it served the purpose

Comment: Nice, i don't know too much how to use "Build ScriptS" but i will study about this subject. Thanks @Mani, i think that is can solve my problem.